# get outerHeight using angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm considering moving from jQuery to Angular but am looking over all my code to see what I will need to replace.

I use the .outerHeight() function to get users screen height. Is there something like this in angular? or do I have to use native JS?

Is it wrong to include jQuery since angular seems to be lacking on DOM manipulation?

Comment: I guess I can just use window.innerWidth since angularJS doesn't work with IE7 or lower.

Comment: It's not 'wrong' to use jquery...Angular uses a scaled down version of jquery OOTB. Just include it on your page before you include angular.js and it'll use the version of jquery you add.

Comment: ++ Although angular does include jquery functions, and can work perfectly well with jquery, it is intended only to be used in very specific portions of your code, (directives), in order to maintain separation of concerns. There is a very good post on moving from jquery to angular development here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background